# Black spots on the stem of my mint plant

Tags: mint

Its been a while that i brought this mint plant and it appears to have gotten black spots on its stem what to do?.Note the plant is in an ac room and i dont give it direct sunlight but it gets the sunlight from the window behind it also i water it if its looks dry or after a few days. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Need to know which mint this plant is and a picture of the entire plant.  Where it is growing, indoors out of doors in the sun under a porch roof???  Are all nodes black like this?  Oh I see one that is not.  What do you do for watering?  Is this in a pot?  With drainage?  Fertilizer?  Please send a few more pictures!!  Quickly!

Answer (score 3):

I think you're saying your mint plant gets daylight, but doesn't ever get any direct sun - if that's the case, its not ideal, mint is a herb and appreciates some direct sun.

You haven't said what the plant is growing in, but as you're keeping it indoors, I assume its potted. If the pot doesn't have drainage holes,  or is standing in an outer container in which excess water sits, that may explain what's happening, because it looks as if your plant has a fungal infection which is likely coming from the root, though its hard to be sure because so little of the plant is visible in the picture. You may want to post a couple more photos showing the whole plant and what it's growing in.